# How to make a array in jquery by the using class

Tags: jquery, arrays

How to make a array in jquery using class.when click a button

```
<table id="tblResult">
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Sony</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Samsung</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">LG</td>
</tr>
```

using this class "clsPhone"
i want this type of array.

```
var arr = [Sony,Samsung,LG];
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = $("#tblResult tr td").map(function(){


return $(this).text()
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblResult">
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Sony</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Samsung</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">LG</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

1. Use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
 var arr = [];
    $('.tblRows').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).find('.clsPhone').text)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var arr = new Array();

$('#tblResult').find('.clsPhone').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [];
$('.clsPhone').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).html());
});

console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblResult">
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Sony</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Samsung</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">LG</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript

```js
var t = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("clsPhone")).map(e=>e.innerHTML);
console.log(t)
```

```html
<table id="tblResult">
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Sony</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">Samsung</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblRows">
    <td class="clsPhone">LG</td>
</tr>
```